# Custom template for Export to Excel using Power automate and Power apps

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

i create power apps trigger option and next and  create Compose action and next create csv table and next create file and next create file share link using path and next Response and submit the power automate flow next i bind the flow in power apps and trigger action using collect and store the date in collect function

I Create an flow using power automate to insert gallery data into Excel but the result has been showing in vertical instead Horizontal in Excel

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).